# JSON parsing using Swift 4

Tags: json, parsing, swift4

Im totally new to networking and parsing. I have spent 2 straight days trying to figure out how I can display the items from this [api](http://api.alquran.cloud/quran/en.asad). For example I need all the names or any object from the api I have zero knowledge and I tried surfing the internet for a solution I cant find for my case. Here is my code:

```
struct Result: Codable {
    var number: [String:Int]
    var text: [String:String]
}

struct Surahs: Codable {
    var data: Surah
}

struct Surah: Codable {
    var surahs: [SurahItem]
}

struct SurahItem: Codable {
    var number: Int?
    var text: String?
}

enum CodingKey:String, Swift.CodingKey {
    case name = "name"
    case text = "text"
    case number = "number"
}

import UIKit

class afasyVC: UIViewController {

    func jsonDecoding() {
        let jsonUrlString = "http://api.alquran.cloud/quran/en.asad"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            do {
                let quraanJsonStuff =  try JSONDecoder().decode(SurahItem.self, from: data)
                for numbers in [quraanJsonStuff] {
                    print(quraanJsonStuff)
                }
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json", jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please describe the steps you have taken to debug your code and exactly where the issues lie

Comment: Thankyou, when i play arround with things it gives me "No value associated with key number (\"number\").", underlyingError: nil)) and sometimes decoder expected to decode an array but dictionary was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSONDecoder` in Swift 4 transforms the JSON collection types as follows:

- A JSON dictionary `{}` to a Swift struct / class.
- A JSON array `[]` to a Swift array.

According to the JSON the structure is

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let code: Int
    let status: String
    let data : Surah
}

struct Surah: Codable {
    let surahs: [SurahItem]
}

struct SurahItem: Codable {
    let number: Int
    let name: String
    let englishName : String 
    // ... and so on
}
```

In the root object there is a dictionary for key `data` which contains the array for key `surahs`

---

To decode and print the `SurahItem` array write

```
let root =  try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
for surah in root.data.surahs {
     print(surah.number, surah.name, surah.englishName)
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly THX alot !