# Get Values from Push Notification iOS Swift 4

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, swift4

I Implement Push Notification in my application. When someone send me a message i received data against that message, I want to perform some action with that data i received but i am unable to get values. Here is my code.

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")

    guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: remoteMessage.appData, options:.prettyPrinted),
    let prettyPrinted = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else { return }
    print("Received direct channel message:\n\(prettyPrinted)")
}
```

Here is my console Output.

```
Received data message: [AnyHashable("chat"): {"date":"1 second(s) 
ago","img":"http:\/\/adforest-testapp.scriptsbundle.com\/wp- 
content\/plugins\/adforest-rest-api\/images\/user.jpg","ad_id":"439","id":244,"text":"hi","type":"reply"}, 
AnyHashable("adId"): 439, AnyHashable("from"): 170168176816, 
AnyHashable("title"): Honda Civic 2017 Type R, AnyHashable("message"): 
hi, AnyHashable("senderId"): 47, AnyHashable("recieverId"): 1, 
AnyHashable("topic"): chat, AnyHashable("type"): receive]
```

Here is my Pretty Printed JSON.
Received direct channel message:

```
{
"chat" : "{\"date\":\"1 second(s) 
ago\",\"img\":\"http:\\\/\\\/adforest-testapp.scriptsbundle.com\\\/wp- 
content\\\/plugins\\\/adforest-rest-api\\\/images\\\/user.jpg\",\"ad_id\":\"439\",\"id\":244,\"text\":\"hi\",\"type\":\"reply\"}",
"adId" : "439",
"from" : "170168176816",
"title" : "Honda Civic 2017 Type R",
"message" : "hi",
"senderId" : "47",
"recieverId" : "1",
"topic" : "chat",
"type" : "receive"
}
```

Kindly guide me how I get key value from this and used to perform some action.

Comment: what you want above response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON parsing using Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47869620/json-parsing-using-swift-4)

Comment: @JigarDarji i wan to access Id, message, type etc. but i am not able to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
let chat = remoteMessage.appData[AnyHashable("chat")]
let adId = remoteMessage.appData[AnyHashable("adId")]
let from = remoteMessage.appData[AnyHashable("from")]
let title = remoteMessage.appData[AnyHashable("title")]
let message = remoteMessage.appData[AnyHashable("message")]
let topic = remoteMessage.appData[AnyHashable("topic")]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")

    guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: remoteMessage.appData, options:.prettyPrinted),
    let prettyPrinted = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else { return }
    print("Received direct channel message:\n\(prettyPrinted)")
    let chatDic = prettyPrinted["chat"] as Dictionary<String, Any>
    let dataString = chatDic["date"] as String
    let img = chatDic["img"] as String
    let ad_id = chatDic["ad_id"] as String
    let id = chatDic["id"] as Int
    let text = chatDic["text"] as String
    let type = chatDic["type"] as String
}
```

Comment: This answer will give multiple errors, for example there are two "data" variables.

Comment: May be, because i have no xcode now.But its logically correct. @SharadChauhan

Comment: prettyPrinted is String type, you cannot fetch value like that from String.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var json = Populate(NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSDictionary)
    var chat = json["chat"] as! Chat
         var adId = json["adId"] as! String
         var from = json["from"] as! String
         var title = json["title"] as! String
         var message = json["message"] as! String
         var senderId = json["senderId"] as! String
         var recieverId = json["recieverId"] as! String
         var topic = json["topic"] as! String
         var type = json["type"] as! String
```